# How to determine kernel version from linux vm snapshot

Tags: linux, virtualbox, forensics

I am having trouble figuring out how to determine the linux kernel version by analyzing a memory snapshot from a linux VM. I have used hexdump to examine the binary but can't find anything that would explicitly tell me what the version is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`uname -r` can be used to determine the exact kernel version of your linux OS. or you can use `uname -a` for all information regarding the kernel version.

Comment: the thing is I'm not running linux i just have a memory snapshot or (.dd) file that i have to analyze. The file is memory.dd if I run the following command: `uname -r memory.dd` nothing happens